# Is there any speed to gain when loading multiple files from disk in parallel?

Tags: python, file-io, parallel-processing, io, multiprocessing

I am working on a project (written in `python 2.7`) where I process a few 1000 images, each about 2.7MB in size. Currently, the workflow goes as follows:

- 1 process loads the images from disk sequentially into a `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()`
- `N` processes consume images from the queue for preprocessing and store the results in a second queue
- 1 process takes the images from the second queue and saves them to disk (smaller files, not really a problem)

So far, this works quite well and I can spawn enough preprocessing processes, so that the loading from disk becomes the bottleneck.

For fun and learning, I was experimenting with using 2 processes that each load half of the files from disk and put them in the same queue. I wanted to see if that would give me even faster loading times from disk.
However, due to my setup (HDDs with ZFS and various caching layers), the results of this "optimization" are inconclusive and can vary a lot even between two identical runs. The numbers *kind of* suggest that loading in parallel is a lot faster, but with all the caching going on, I've lost trust in the timings (values from 55s to 7s and all in between have been happening...).
Additionally, I am testing on a Linux system so far, but the production machine is running Windows with an SSD. So whatever results I get here in testing, they might be OS-specific and not apply to the final use-case.

My question is: Is there any agreed-upon benefit in loading multiple files in parallel? Or, is it enough to have 1 process load all files sequentially, as it will already read as fast as the HDD permits? I'm not necessarily looking for answers specific to python, but file-I/O in general.
Are there any important differences between Linux and Windows?

---

Disclaimer:
I'm aware that this could be solved by excessive benchmarking on the target machine. However, a comprehensive benchmark would require a lot of code rewriting at this point and more access time (and maybe reboots, to clear the filesystem caches) on the target machine than I currently have.

Comment: Since the file-loading would very likely be I/O bound, doing it in two processes might actually be slower due to the additional overhead it requires.

Comment: @martineau Not on an SSD. Pending several reads at once is essential to get great performance from them.

Comment: you could bench that at your program startup, just to decide to do that in parallel or sequential. A lot of programs have startup benches to know which algorithm is best depending on the current hardware

Comment: OK, if you're using an SSD then that part is not I/O bound...but why are  your trying to speed that part up then? Have you profiled your code to see where it's actually spending most of its time?

Comment: This depends hardly on your setup, is only remotely programming related and also too broad. Not a good topic for SO.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, that was one of my ideas. However, I wasn't sure how "pending" multiple reads in parallel would be

Comment: @martineau from my profiling, it's clear that loading the files from disk is the bottleneck. However, I have trouble determining if loading files with multiple threads is beneficial, as runtimes can vary so much due to caching, so I was hoping for some best practices or guidelines

Comment: OK, since the processing of data while loading is what's slowing that step down, it must actually be Compute-bound rather than I/O-bound—in which case multi-threading likely won't help because Python doesn't actually run more than one thread at a time due to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) that prevents that from happening except during I/O and to calls to functions in some C-based extension modules.

Comment: @martineau No, it's definitely I/O-bound. The caching I was referring to is filesystem-caching. Also, I don't do multithreading, but multiprocessing. As far as I know, the difference here is exactly that multiprocessing doesn't suffer from the GIL-related problems.

Comment: This is unfortunately too broad, imo to be a good fit here. There are several good questions you could extract though. Anyway, one pro-tip: you can test multithreading performance versus multiprocessing performance in python 2.7 with the `multiprocessing.dummy` module. Just swap them out as they share an interface and see whether you care about the GIL to begin with: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy

Comment: Passing large amounts of data between separate processes, as it sounds like would be necessary here, would also impose a huge amount of overhead and, again, result in slower, not faster times.